# GPS NMEA - is VTG 'Course' the same as RMC 'Course over ground'?

Tags: gps, nmea

I have been reading up on NMEA messages [here](https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/GPS-sentences-or-NMEA-sentences.html) and other places, but it isn't obvious to me if the VTG message 1 (Course) is the same as RMC message 8 (Course over ground). They use the same number for the degrees, so I could infer it is the same data, but it would be nice to know for sure.

Comment: Assuming similar to sailing, then COG is the actual direction the vessel is moving, whilst course is the direction the vessel is pointing; they can be the same but often not depending on speed of vessel and influences of wind, tide, currents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my aviation and land vehicle experience, "Course" and "Course over ground" are used interchangeably and they mean the same thing.  For a vehicle (a car or tractor or aircraft), we'd use "Heading" for the direction it is pointing in.  The comment by nmtoken suggests that for sailing, "course" is used for the direction the vessel is pointing in - that doesn't surprise me, terminology tends to vary depending on occupation.

As usual, the contents of "Course" probably depends on the manufacturer and on the type and age of equipment.

A typical GPS receiver (for land, air, or water use) does not have any way to know what direction it (or the vehicle) is pointing in so all it can do is calculate the direction of movement by comparing successive positions, and that clearly will give the course over ground.  So for a GPS, VTG Course will have the same value as RMC COG.

If you have a marine or aviation autopilot or similar equipment, it may have inputs from a magnetic compass as well as from a GPS so it could give Heading (the direction the vehicle is pointing is in) or course (the direction the vehicle is moving in).  But I think an Aviation Autopilot would still use the same value for Course and COG, no idea on the Marine side.

NOTE:  If you have a marine autopilot, it wouldn't output "$**GP**VTG" because that's specific to GPS - the "**GP**" part is referred to as the Talker.  See [this website](https://www.tronico.fi/OH6NT/docs/NMEA0183.pdf) for a list of talkers.

Comment: Thank you. Your detailed explanation is great. This is for a land GPS with dual GPS to calculate heading, so Course and COG should be the same then.

Comment: Be aware that NMEA doesn't always have quite the right contents (what it says on the box is not what the box contains!) - it wouldn't surprise me if a company making a dual-GNSS system decided they would put Heading in RMC and Course in VTG.  But I would expect this information to be in their documentation of NMEA sentences.

Comment: I should have clarified. We are creating the dual GPS using open source code and ZED-F9P to transmit GPS to a proprietary mapping program. I had written some more info in my original post but then it got closed due to not having a single cohesive question. :roll-eyes

Comment: "closed due to not having a single cohesive question" - yup, it happens.  I did have a response marked as not relevant / off topic by a moderator who didn't understand, I didn't bother to fight it.